# Getting value out of a computed observable

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So I'm kinda new to Knockout and I have this issue which I need help with. I thinks it's something simple but I just can't seem to figure it out.
The issue is that I have this computed that basically returns the src for and  and I have this Overlay that's supposed to appear on top of the image ONLY if part of the img srcs contains certain string.
So basically I'm trying to bind the visible of the overlay (which are basically 3 ) to a computed which first check for a checkbox to see if it's checked and then the idea is that it would also ask for the value of the computed used for the src and once I get that value I can return if it contains the string that I want to validate it against, and the issue I'm having is actually getting the value of the computed that returns the srs of the  as a String so that I can validate it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide and I hope you have a nice day!!

```
self.model.SelectedImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.model.SelectedImageIndex() > -1 && self.model.SelectedImageIndex() < self.model.ViolationImages().length) {
        return self.model.ViolationImages()[self.model.SelectedImageIndex()].ImagePath();
    }
    return "../../Content/img/spacer.gif";
});

//2DOverlay Display Lines
self.model.ShowOverlayLines = ko.computed(function () {
    //Validate if image is OV 1 or not to display Overlay Lines
    //Get the STRING VALUE of SelectedImagePath and Check if ()
    return self.model.SelectedImagePath() && BarsChecked && self.model.ShowOverlayLines;
});
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is.  Many post more of your model, HTML and/or a jsFiddle

Comment: The only think I'm trying to find out is if I can unwrap the value of the SelectedImagePath computed into a simple string

Comment: simple string ? try JSON.ToStringify(//observable) . it might work

Answer (score 0):

Do this method.
Firstly add this event in your databind in your html :

```
<input class=" input-file" id="fileUpload" type="file" data-bind="event: { change: _updateImg}" />
```

Next, create the function _updateImg in your js file, this function replace your data img (will apear in your tag html img) :

```
function _updateImg(data, event) {
        var me = this, files, reader;
        files = event.currentTarget.files;

        if (files.length > 0) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                me.pictureUrl(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    };
```

My bindingHandlers change the url of my img (manage errors) :

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.img = {

    // Mise à jour de l'image
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Données de l'observable
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            src = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value.src),
            fallback = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value.fallback),
            $element = $(element);

        // On set l'url de l'image, si fichier innaccesible alors on set le src à fallback (url par défaut)
        if (src) {
            $element.attr("src", src);
        } else {
            $element.attr("src", fallback);
        }
    },

    // Init de l'image
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $element = $(element);

        $element.error(function () {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                fallback = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value.fallback);

            $element.attr("src", fallback);
        });
    }
};
```

Need to your html in your html tag :

```
<img class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" data-bind="img: { src: pictureUrl, fallback: _pictureDefault }" />
```

My observbale "pictureUrl" is my final url. 
My obseravble pictureDefault is my default picture when I never change this img.
Ask me if u want some help.